# SSRS doesn't insert page break when the page table is empty

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I created a report that has 3 named tabs when exporting to Excel.  All 3 pages consist of one tablix each and I selected each tablix and click on Add a Page Break After in the tablix properties.  And in the F4 properties for each tablix I give them each a name under PageName, to name the Excel tabs.  And END is selected under PageBreak/Breaklocation
the problem is that when one of the tablixes returns zero rows based on the query for that day it includes the tablix from the following page on that page.  The header for the empty tablix is at the top of the page and the header and table from the following tab is right underneath, on the same page.  Am I leaving out a step?

Comment: Hmm...I usually add the Page Break at the START - maybe this is why.

Comment: The suggestion above is correct. Use page break at start except the first tablix and you ll be fine. @HannoverFist you should write it as answer!

Comment: Thanks @hannover fist, that did it.